# System out of memory exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, out-of-memory

We have working on a client server socket programming using Visual studio C# 2010 and SQL SERVER.

The program works fine. But after some time it stumble on the error

```
"System out of memory exception"
```

Here we use a socket packet class

```
 public class SocketPacket
 {
        public SocketPacket(System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket, int clientNumber, string ClientIP)
        {
            m_currentSocket = socket;
            m_clientNumber = clientNumber;
            m_ClientIP = ClientIP;
        }
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
        public int m_clientNumber;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[10000000];
        public string m_ClientIP;
    }
```

I think the dataBuffer get full

How to free the dataBuffer?

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.Socket is Idisposible, so you need manualy dispose it.

Comment: thanks for the response its working but after the dispose the client getting disconnected. how to manage that.

Answer (score 2):

Yours `SocketPacket` class contains field of type `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` that implements `IDisposible` interface, in this cause you should manualy dispose instances of your class. Also I suggest you to implement IDisposible in `SocketPacket` class.

```
    public class SocketPacket: IDisposable
    {
        public SocketPacket(System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket, int clientNumber, string ClientIP)
        {
            m_currentSocket = socket;
            m_clientNumber = clientNumber;
            m_ClientIP = ClientIP;
        }
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
        public int m_clientNumber;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[10000000];
        public string m_ClientIP;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_currentSocket.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response its working but after the dispose the client getting disconnected. how to manage that.

Comment: could you show full `SocketPacket` class source. Maybe you don't need to pass `socket` into this class.

Comment: i m doing the multithread application an d maintaining the list in System.Collections.ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You should check the MSDN report on how to implement IDisposable correctly. This may fix your issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737(v=vs.80).aspx

edit: after some further examination, the C# type Socket also implements IDisposable, so try to use using() blocks around the usage of the Socket objects. This will ensure you clean up the Socket object correctly.